# CKan toolkit.get_action function is giving empty list when sorting by package_count

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, ckan

I'm new to CKAN and encountered a problem with template helpers. Particularly in my case, I will have to invoke `toolkit.get_action('group_list')` in my own template helper. However, when I add the constraint like the following:

```
results = toolkit.get_action('group_list')(data_dict={'sort': 'package_count desc',
                                            'type': 'MyType',
                                            'all_fields': True})
```

The results that I get back is an empty list. If I remove the 'sort' constraint from the `data_dict`, I can get the results of list the groups with 'MyType'. I don't know what caused this problem, because when I followed [ckan toolkit official examples](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.6/theming/templates.html?highlight=toolkit%20get%20group%20list), it works for without any problems. However, what I can think of is this customized group might have its own schema such that package_count can not be used as a sort key. Since there's no error message, I can't make further assumption.

Comment: Looks like you're doing things right, so it sounds like a bug. I suggest you take a look at _group_or_org_list(), stick in a breakpoint (pdb I'd use) and play with the query filters to see why the packages are getting lost from the count.

Comment: @DRead Thanks for letting me know, I've already know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem. The implementation I've showed in my question is correct. However, the database is not being populated properly. Basically you have to populate some packages for the particular groups. If you have no packages within each groups this function will return an empty query result. With the advice of @DRead, I researched the source code of `_group_or_org_list()`. If you take a look at this piece of code:

```
if sort_info and sort_info[0][0] == 'package_count':
    query = model.Session.query(model.Group.id,
                                model.Group.name,
                                sqlalchemy.func.count(model.Group.id))

    query = query.filter(model.Member.group_id == model.Group.id) \
                 .filter(model.Member.table_id == model.Package.id) \
                 .filter(model.Member.table_name == 'package') \
                 .filter(model.Package.state == 'active')
else:
    query = model.Session.query(model.Group.id,
                                model.Group.name)
```

If you don't have packages created for groups, `filter(model.Member.table_id == model.Package.id)` will filter all groups out.